(Godot 3D 3.5) Character mesh rotates completly rotates when the character is in an specific angle
Programing language, game engine and version
GDScript Godot 3.5
problem
Hi, i"m new here programing, i'm programing a 3rd person controller and i have a problem is that the character takes a 360 degs rotation when is in a specific angle
what i tried
i tried using this:
if velocity.length() > 0.2:
        var look_direction = -Vector2(velocity.z, velocity.x)
        var target_angle = look_direction.angle()
        var current_angle = model.rotation.y
        model.rotation.y = lerp(current_angle, look_direction.angle(), rotation_speed * delta)
        print(rad2deg(look_direction.x),rad2deg(look_direction.y) )

but i think that this is causing the problem
here is the code of the character:
extends KinematicBody

enum State {
    Idle,
    IdleInFourPaws,
    Walking,
    WakingInFourPaws,
    Running,
    RunningInFourPaws,
    Crouching,
    InAir
}

var character_movement_state = State

export var mouse_sensivity = 0.1

export var min_camera_angle_limit = -60.0
export var max_camera_angle_limit = 60.0

export var speed = 7.0
export var jump_strength = 20.0
export var gravity = 50.0

var rotation_speed = 7

var velocity = Vector3.ZERO
var snap_vector = Vector3.DOWN

var is_in_air = false

onready var camera_pivot = $camera_pivot
onready var model = $player_Model

func _ready() -> void:
    Input.set_mouse_mode(2)
    
func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:

    if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_cancel") and Input.mouse_mode == 2:
        Input.set_mouse_mode(0)
    elif Input.is_mouse_button_pressed(1) and Input. mouse_mode == 0:
        Input.set_mouse_mode(2)
        
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        camera_pivot.rotation_degrees.x -= event.relative.y * mouse_sensivity
        camera_pivot.rotation_degrees.x = clamp(camera_pivot.rotation_degrees.x, min_camera_angle_limit, max_camera_angle_limit)
    
        camera_pivot.rotation_degrees.y -= event.relative.x * mouse_sensivity
        camera_pivot.rotation_degrees.y = wrapf(camera_pivot.rotation_degrees.y, 0.0, 360.0)

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    var direction = Vector3.ZERO
    
    var move_foreward = Input.get_action_strength("move_forward")
    var move_backwards = Input.get_action_strength("move_backward")
    var move_left = Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    var move_right = Input.get_action_strength("move_right")
    
    if move_foreward:
        direction -= transform.basis.z

    if move_backwards:
        direction += transform.basis.z

    if move_left:
        direction -= transform.basis.x

    if move_right:
        direction += transform.basis.x

    direction = direction.rotated(Vector3.UP, camera_pivot.rotation.y).normalized()
    
    velocity.x = direction.x * speed
    velocity.z = direction.z * speed
    velocity.y -= gravity * delta
    
    var just_landed = is_on_floor() and snap_vector == Vector3.ZERO
    var is_jumping = is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_pressed("jump")
    
    if is_jumping:
        velocity.y = jump_strength
        snap_vector = Vector3.ZERO
        
    elif just_landed:
        snap_vector = Vector3.DOWN
        
    if is_on_floor():
        is_in_air = false
    elif !is_on_floor():
        is_in_air = true
    
    velocity = move_and_slide_with_snap(velocity, snap_vector, Vector3.UP, true)
    
    if velocity.length() > 0.2:
        var look_direction = -Vector2(velocity.z, velocity.x)
        var target_angle = look_direction.angle()
        var current_angle = model.rotation.y
        model.rotation.y = lerp(current_angle, look_direction.angle(), rotation_speed * delta)
        print(rad2deg(look_direction.x),rad2deg(look_direction.y))

what I want to happen is for the character to do the opposite to the full turn that the mesh is doing

Hi, welcome. I haben’t really looked at this, but try using lerp_angle() instead of lerp() to interpolate rotations?

ok, it worked yay, but i forgot to say that the character resets its rotation each time the character jump (or is in air)
